# pandas update a dataframe with values from another dataframe on the match of column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with stock ticker names and dates as two columns, and i would like to update this dataframe with price value from another larger dataframe matching those 2 columns

Eg: df1:

```
ticker  Date
AAPL    2022-01-03
GE      2022-04-18
```

df2:

```
ticker   Date             Close
AAPL     2022-01-02       120
AAPL     2022-01-03       122
AAPL     2022-01-04       125
AAPL     2022-01-05       121
.
.
.
GE     2022-04-16       20
GE     2022-04-17       22
GE     2022-04-18       25
GE     2022-04-19       21
```

The output should be:

```
ticker  Date         Close
AAPL    2022-01-03   122
GE      2022-04-18   25
```

I can do a loop and update row by row, but i would like to check if there is a pythonic way using the whole series/vectors...

Comment: I tried the following: for index, row in init_df.iterrows():
    row['fridayClose'] = allprice_df.loc[(allprice_df["date"]==row['DateIdentified'])& (allprice_df["ticker"]==row['Ticker']),"close"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try merging on those two columns:

```
df1.merge(df2, on = ['ticker', 'Date'], how = 'left')
```

Comment: I am not sure if merging makes sense, df2 is very large with 25M rows, df1 is very small with 500 rows or so...

Comment: @sud It's pandas equivalent to excel vlookup. This is the fastest option.

Comment: Thank you! vlookup comment you made made me understand this better...

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: If you can index your dataframes in advance, ***you can do about 10,000 times better*** than `merge()` for each individual join of two dataframes (one with 500 rows, one with 25 million); if you are doing only a single join of such dataframes, merge() is about as fast as the alternatives.

---

Your question says:

> I have a dataframe with stock ticker names and dates as two columns, and i would like to update this dataframe with price value from another larger dataframe matching those 2 columns

... and you ask:

> i would like to check if there is a pythonic way using the whole series/vectors

If your question is asked in the context of just this single dataframe query, then you probably can't get better performance than `merge()`.

However, if you have the option of initializing your dataframes to use `ticker, Date` as their index, or if you can at least set their indexes to `ticker, Date` before needing to run multiple queries of the kind described in your question, then you can beat `merge()`.

Here is a benchmark of 6 different strategies for df1 with 500 rows and df2 with 25 million rows:

```
Timeit results:
foo_1 (merge) ran in 23.043055499998445 seconds
foo_2 (indexed join) ran in 51.69773360000181 seconds
foo_3 (pre-indexed join) ran in 0.0027679000013449695 seconds
foo_4 (pre-indexed df1 join) ran in 24.431038499998976 seconds
foo_5 (merge right) ran in 22.99117219999971 seconds
foo_6 (pre-indexed assign) ran in 0.007970200000272598 seconds
```

Note that `pre-indexed join` is about 10,000x faster than `merge` (and `pre-indexed assign` is also quick at about 3,000x faster), primarily because pre-indexed dataframes have hash table access by index which have key search time of O(1) vs worst case O(n) time for non-indexed keys. However, `indexed join` is more than twice as slow as `merge` because `indexed join` includes the initial indexing effort (which can be done just once for multiple queries such as the one in your question, and which is excluded from `pre-indexed join`).

Explanation of the various strategies:

- The `merge` strategy uses no indexing.
- The `indexed join` strategy includes the time to index both dataframes.
- The `pre-indexed join` strategy excludes the initial overhead of indexing both dataframes.
- The `pre-indexed df1 join` strategy excludes the initial overhead of indexing df1 but works with an unindexed df2.
- The `merge right` strategy swaps df1 and df2 as object and argument of `merge()`.
- The `pre-indexed assign` strategy doesn't use `merge()` or `join()`, instead doing an index-aligned assignment from df2 to a new column in df1.

Here's the code for each strategy:

```py
df1_orig = pd.DataFrame([('A'+str(i) , f'{2020+i//365}-{(i//28)%12 + 1}-{i%28 + 1}') for i in range(500)], columns=['ticker', 'Date'])
print(df1_orig)

df2_orig = pd.DataFrame([('A'+str(i) , f'{2020+(i%500)//365}-{((i%500)//28)%12 + 1}-{(i%500)%28 + 1}', (10 * i + 1) % 300) for i in range(25_000_000)], columns=['ticker', 'Date', 'Close'])
print(df2_orig)

df1_indexed_orig = df1_orig.set_index(['ticker', 'Date'])
df2_indexed_orig = df2_orig.set_index(['ticker', 'Date'])

# merge
def foo_1(df1, df2):
    df1 = df1.merge(df2, on = ['ticker', 'Date'], how = 'left')
    return df1

# indexed join
def foo_2(df1, df2):
    df1.set_index(['ticker', 'Date'], inplace=True)
    df2.set_index(['ticker', 'Date'], inplace=True)
    df1 = df1.join(df2)
    return df1

# pre-indexed join
def foo_3(df1, df2):
    # called with df1_indexed_orig and df2_indexed_orig
    df1 = df1.join(df2)
    return df1

# pre-indexed df1 join
def foo_4(df1, df2):
    # called with df1_indexed_orig
    df1 = df2.join(df1, on = ['ticker', 'Date'], how = 'right')
    return df1

# merge right
def foo_5(df1, df2):
    df1 = df2.merge(df1, on = ['ticker', 'Date'], how = 'right')
    return df1

# pre-indexed assign
def foo_6(df1, df2):
    # called with df1_indexed_orig and df2_indexed_orig
    df1 = df1.assign(Close=df2.Close)
    return df1
```